# Powercenter - SetVariable always is zero

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I have a problem when assigning a variable mapping.

[image]

It is assigned an expression and then to review it in the Workflow this are in Zero

[image]

Comment: What is the value you're trying to set it to? How the variable is defined (aggregation)?

Comment: I found the problem , it was a value field taking a flat file exceeded the decimal type ( 11).
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , it was a value field taking a flat file exceeded the decimal type ( 11).
Thank you